# Can you connect a risograph to a pc running linux?

Tags: print-design, linux, risograph

We're trying to connect a Riso MZ7U to a computer running Ubuntu.

The link to download official drivers from Riso is https://www.riso.com/download/

They only have drivers available for Windows and Mac.

Has anyone ever successfully connected a Riso to a computer running Linux? Are there any unofficial or third party drivers available?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Riso support.

Comment: If asking a Stack Exchange site, I would think this questions fits better at the Unix or SuperUser Stack Exchange.